# How to add a default value in record type? - F#

Tags: c#, f#

I was wondering if it is possible to add an initial value to the property of a type record.

```fs
type ToDo = {
   Title : string
   Description : string
   Done : bool
}
```

Something like this:

```fs
Done : bool option = false
```

That is, I want to do something like in C # :

```cs
 public class Todo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool Done { get; set; } = false; // Just like this
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, F# does not have default values for record fields. The usual way to go about this is to provide a "smart constructor" - i.e. a function that takes whatever fields are not default and constructs a record for you:

```
let toDo title description = 
    { Title = title; Description = description; Done = false }

let firstTodo = toDo "Buy milk" "The cat is hungry"
```

If you want the API to look nicer, you could also leverage anonymous records:

```
let toDo (r : {| Title: string; Description: string |}) = 
    { Title = r.Title; Description = r.Description; Done = false }

let firstTodo = toDo {| Title = "Buy milk"; Description = "The cat is hungry" |}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, (only recommended if there are valid defaults for all fields) to Fyodors solution is to use "with" in functions. Like this:

```
type ToDo = {
   Title : string
   Description : string
   Done : bool
}
module ToDo = 
    let defaultValues = 
        {Title = "Give me a title"; Description = "Describe me"; Done = false}

let myToDoItem = {ToDo.defaultValues with Title = "A real title"; Description = "A real description}
```